# IllegalArgumentException Moshi thinks I'm using ArrayList(java) when I'm using List(Kotlin)

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing, ktor, moshi

I'm new to Kotlin and I still don't fully get the syntax for some stuff, expecially inside a lambda. I'm trying to build a simple REST api for uni project, currently messing with ktor, exposed and moshi.
However I'm getting the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No JsonAdapter for class java.util.ArrayList, you should probably use List instead of ArrayList (Moshi only supports the collection interfaces by default) or else register a custom JsonAdapter.`

I'm not sure how to solve that, because I do use a List, however my guess is that Kotlin lists are compiled down to java's ArrayList.

From from what I've googled, this should work and be enough, but I guess it's not the case:

```
    val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Author::class.java)
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<Author>> = moshi.adapter(listType)
```

Here is the full code (except the database settings/connection):

```
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    install(CallLogging)
    val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, Author::class.java)
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val adapter: JsonAdapter<List<Author>> = moshi.adapter(listType)
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        /*gson {
            setPrettyPrinting()
        }*/
        moshi(moshi)
    }

    routing {
        get("/authors") {
            val authorList = mutableListOf<Author>()
            transaction(db) {
                addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
                SchemaUtils.create(Authors)
                val query = "SELECT a.id, a.name, a.age, c.name as `country`\n" +
                        " FROM authors a, countries c\n" +
                        " WHERE a.country_id = c.id ORDER BY a.id";
                TransactionManager.current().exec(query) { rs ->
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        authorList += Author(
                            id = rs.getInt("id"), name = rs.getString("name"),
                            age = rs.getInt("age"), country = rs.getString("country")
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            val result: List<Author> = authorList.toList()
            adapter.toJson(result)
            print("\n\n${result}\n\n")
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)
        }
    }
}
```

My data class looks like this:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Author(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val country: String
)
```

I do have the required dependencies to install moshi for ktor from [here](https://github.com/plannigan/ktor-moshi)

If I try on single object it will probably work, but I need the whole list from the query output.

I also did try making a custom adapter as the error suggests, but then it couldn't find my `@ToJson` anotated method.

If I use GSON it just works magically, however I want to figure out how to do it with moshi. Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t know anything about moshi and this is a complete guess, but try putting `java.util.List::class.java` so you aren’t passing the Kotlin List type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not quite sure what you mean either, If you're talking about changing my toJson call like this `adapter.toJson(result::class.java) ` , it doesn't work. I'm getting 

`Type mismatch. Required: List<Author>? Found: Class<out List<Author>> `

Answer (score 1):

I found out my mistake, it's probably really stupid, but due to the magic of gson I couldn't figure out how to use moshi properly. I really didn't expect that I have to use the adapter.

`call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)`

should be:

`call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, adapter.toJson(result))`